# Removing possibility of injecting dangerous SQL queries

Tags: sql, sql-injection

There is a function having a parameter. The function internally invokes a stored procedure with the parameter. And clients can pass a string to the function through HTTP requests.

I'm trying to add a method to remove any possibilities of injecting dangerous SQL statement through the parameter. The method name is IsSQLParameterSafe() and it returns boolean values depending on the parameter. If the value is safe to execute, then the method will return true, otherwise it returns false.

In my case, the parameter doesn't have to have blanks so if there are any whitespaces, then it'll return false. Also, I'm going to limit the length of the input up to 64 because its the maximum length of the parameter.

Do you think that my idea will work? If not, can you suggest ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Sounds like you are being overly cautious. If you are not executing dynamic SQL in the stored procedure, you should be fine with the parameter being handled by the database libraries.

Comment: Define what are acceptable values for the parameter and match it against a white-list.   You'll probably get some pointers if you indicate what the parameter is used for...

Comment: Why not just use Prepared statements and let the database handle this stuff for you.

Comment: @Oded Could you please tell more specific? What libraries are you talking about?

Comment: @Sparky I think that having a white-list could be nice.

Comment: I am being as specific as you are. The libraries that you use to connect your code to the database.

Comment: @crush I should take a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't need to worry, unless you are stitching the SQL together manually and then executing it with the EXEC command.

For example, this is a simple Stored Procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE DeleteRecord
(
@name VARCHAR(64)
)
AS
BEGIN
DELETE FROM Records WHERE [Name] = @name
END
```

If you attempt to pass this string into the procedure...

```
name OR 1=1
```

...then the Procedure will Delete 0 records, because no one has this exact name.

**Why doesn't it delete everything?**

The Stored Procedure doesn't stitch the SQL together into a big string (you often see this sort of thing in tutorials for beginners in PHP). Instead, it passes the original SQL statement, then each parameter as a distinct argument. I don't know the technical details of how this works, but I know from experience that adding slashes and quotes and garbled characters will not break this query.

***But...***

If you are writing Dynamic SQL, and if you parameter represents a Table or Column name, then you need to be more careful. I would use a white list for that.

http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html

Comment: Mine is dynamic SQL and I think having a whitelist is the most secure and easy to implement.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a parameterized query even with stored procedures.  This is the best way to deal with SQL injection risks.  It's difficult to be more specific without knowing what language you're using, but in Java, for example, you'd use something similar to this:

```
String callStmt = "CALL PROC(?)";
PreparedStatement prepStmt = con.prepareStatement(callStmt);
prepStmt.setString(1, parameter);
ResultSet rs = prepStmt.executeQuery();
```

You might also be interested in the OWASP [SQL Injection Prevention Cheat Sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet), which goes into more detail.

Comment: Do I make sure that prepared statements remove all possibility of SQL injection attacks? (FYI, I'm using C#)

Comment: That's part of their purpose, yes. The DB driver will escape the parameters you pass in.

Comment: Yes, SQL injection is impossible with Prepared Statements. (Failure would involve an error in the DB driver, something that is probably mature and very well-tested for this.)